# How to make MariaDB log in JSON format?

Tags: mariadb

In MySQL you can make logging appear in JSON format by installing `component_log_sink_json` component and enabling this component:

```sql
INSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_log_sink_json';
SET PERSIST log_error_services = 'log_filter_internal; log_sink_json';
```

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log-json.html

But this does not work in MariaDB:

```
MariaDB > INSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_log_sink_json';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMPONENT 'file://component_log_sink_json'' at line 1
```

```
MariaDB > SET log_error_services = 'log_filter_internal; log_sink_json';
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'log_error_services'
```

How can I make MariaDB log in JSON format?

Comment: You can't. And there is not INSTALL COMPONENT either, neither log_error_services variable. What do you need this for?

Comment: This is very unfortunate. The reason I want structured logging is that our log management system (Splunk) can extract fields (e.g. which HY-code the error contained) and easily create custom alarms, graphs or searches based on specific fields, instead of relying on RegEx to extract content from an unstructured message. I must say that I find it odd that MariaDB doesn't support structured logging.